# Removing globally registered JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json, enums, json.net

I have implementation of JsonConverter called LocalizedStringEnumConverter which serializes enums to localized strings, and as such is registered globally in Global.asax via JsonSettings with the syntax:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
    {
        new LocalizedStringEnumConverter()
    }
};
```

Now at one place, I do not want to use the converter, I want enum to be serialized as it would usually - as a number.

So I've tried to create new instance of JsonSerializerSettings and pass it like this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter>() 
};
```

And then call serialize with these settings (hoping that globally registered converter will be overridden:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObjectContainingEnumProperty, jsonSettings)
```

However, as a result, I again get enums serialized with my LocalizedStringEnumConverter.

Is there a way to remove globally registered converter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`JsonSerializer.Create()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Create.htm) to create a JsonSerializer which avoids the default settings.

```
var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create();
string s;
using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
   serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, someObjectContainingEnumProperty);
   s = stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

Comment: From the description of the mentioned method: Creates a new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer instance.  The Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer will use default settings.

Comment: the answer has a typo, it should be   serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, someObjectContainingEnumProperty);

Comment: @liuhongbo Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov You want `JsonSerializer.Create()` to avoid the default settings.  `JsonSerializer.CreateDefault()` *uses* the default settings.  See [the documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer.htm).